# Stored procedure to get Employee Task data comma seperated in Sql server 2008 as backend and Asp.net mvc3 as frontend

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to write an stored procedure for SQl server 2008 to get all Tasks of a employee comma separated and want to display that in a single column in next table. In front of EmployeeID, all task should be displayed for a paprticular employee comma separated..
My table is:

```
TableID int Primary key
EmployeeID  int 
Task  varchar(50)
```

I will pass EmployeeID as  a parameter.
How can I write this Stored Procedure???
Please help me..

Comment: It would be better to do this reformatting in you display code, rather than trying to do it in the database. Although there are kludgey ways to do it, SQL Server's string formatting facilities are comparatively weak.

Comment: I tried to do this in my controller,but it is getting a tedious job,hance want to write Stored Porcedure..

Comment: instead of sp it will better to use function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi It can be done in Sp but not the efficient way 
1) Fetch the all records for that particular coloum in one Varchar2
2) Open one result set for string.
3) take one record in one var. append ',' assign back to new varchar2

```
current_count:=1
task_result_String = 'select task from tabel' 
total_task_count='select total task count' 

OPEN rset FOR task_result _string;
       LOOP
         FETCH rset INTO t_result;
           EXIT WHEN  rset%NOTFOUND;
          if( current_count =total_task_count) THEN
          task_final_result:=task_final_result||t_result;
          END IF;
         if( b_count <v_count)  THEN`enter code here`
        task_final_result:=task_final_result||t_result||',';
          END IF;
          curerent_count:=current_count+1;
          dbms_output.put_line('task with comma seperated'||task_final_result);
      END LOOP;
```

Here taken care not to append ',' comma at last and if only one record